# Is there any access permission for "MY" store for adding certificate through code

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, x509certificate

I have written a simple c++ code which add certificate into "MY" store. I tested the code, it's working. I would want to run this application as windows service based.

So, I've created a new service in windows which will read certificate from file system and insert into local "MY" store.

Also I created a log file, when I ran my service log file says certificate successfully inserted into "MY" store but I unable to find certificate in "MY" known as Personal store.

[image]

Is there any access permission of current user "MY" Store when an application runs as windows service? If no, then what could be the reason for this?

Comment: the "MY" is per concrete user SID. the service usually have another SID that concrete user. you simply use different stores. so service (it run as localsystem *S-1-5-18* ?) have self "MY" store, you user, under which you run snapin - have another "MY" store

Comment: Thank a lot @RbMm. Can you please tell me how to add the certificate in the user SID?

Comment: you can impersonate user before call `CertOpenStore`

Comment: I were using `CertOpenSystemStore`function. If you don't mind, can you tell me how to impersonate user?

Comment: you need have some info about user - it token, calling process/thread, etc. for which user you want open store ? exist multiple user. based on what you select ?

Comment: I were using the below code for impersonate user `HANDLE hToken; if(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken)) { ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken) }` but still certificate not available under current user account

Comment: what sense impersonate to **self** process token `GetCurrentProcess()` ? you need impersonate **user** process

Comment: Not to mention that the code violates a very strong security advisory: running as a high-privilege service, you **MUST** check the return value of `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`. The current code is an exploit waiting to happen.

Comment: Let me re-ask the question that RbMm is implying. Say you have a system with 5 users, 2 of which are logged in interactively and one that's logged in remotely. (Yes, that's possible). Which of those 5 certificate stores should the service use? Which of those 5 should it impersonate, and why?